# How to delete entire row from Parse.com and update it with new data

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, cloud

**Code for Deleting**

```
            DeleteDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ParseObject Details = new ParseObject("Details");

                ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                Details.put("User", user);

                Details.remove("Age");
                Details.remove("Email_Address");
                Details.remove("Location");
                Details.remove("FullName");

                Details.saveInBackground();

            }
        });
```

I have created the code above, it deletes the data from the table on Parse however it automatically creates a new field. I want to be able to enter data, delete it and enter it again. Once the user exits the application and returns to it, the data is fetched from the cloud and displayed in TextViews.

**Code for TextView**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> requestAge = ParseQuery.getQuery("Details");
        requestAge.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            public void done(ParseObject reqDetails, ParseException e) {
                if (reqDetails != null) {
                    Log.d("reqDetails", "Got it");
                    //Retrieve Age
                    String gettheAge = reqDetails.getString("Age");
                    EditText displayAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageET);
                    displayAge.setText(gettheAge);

                    //Retrieve E-mail address
                    String gettheEmail = reqDetails.getString("Email_Address");
                    EditText displayEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailET);
                    displayEmail.setText(gettheEmail);

                    //Retrieve Location:
                    String gettheLocation = reqDetails.getString("Location");
                    EditText displayLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LocationET);
                    displayLocation.setText(gettheLocation);

                    //Retrieve Name:
                    String gettheName = reqDetails.getString("FullName");
                    EditText displayName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameET);
                    displayName.setText(gettheName);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Successfully Recieved Personal Details",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Log.d("reqAge", "Empty_query");


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Can't Get Details, Check Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete an object in Parse, simply call the `deleteInBackground` method on the object you want to delete.

[Android Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-deleting)

Comment: I have, however it only deletes the Age, Location, Name and E-mail Address. It doesn't delete the whole row. In addition, it also creates a new row so I cant delete the data and save it again for it to show up in the TextViews (If that makes sense).

Comment: [This sounds like someone who's experiencing a similar problem](https://parse.com/questions/deleting-like-pfobject-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to delete a specific row by it's ID :

```
//"Status" is the tableName in parse.com
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Status");
//"objectId" the column name in parse.com
//objectID is the content ID in the table objectId
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", objectID);
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(ParseObject status, ParseException e) {
   try {
         status.delete();
         status.saveInBackground();
       }catch(ParseException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
 });
```

Hop this helps good luck.